# Always showing some warnings in a new project of phonegap

Tags: android, ios, xcode, cordova

I have worked with several apps in phonegap. Every time I build a new project by using the given steps in following link of phonegap docs:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html

**But I have seen in every case there is 15 warnings always there**:

```
/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/BramAutoGroup/Classes/AppDelegate.m:81:25: 'useSplashScreen' is deprecated: Deprecated in Cordova 2.5. Add/Remove the SplashScreen plugin instead of setting this property. 

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFile.m:804:54: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'unsigned long'

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFile.m:805:108: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFile.m:1075:54: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'unsigned long'

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFile.m:1076:108: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFile.m:1282:98: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long long' to 'int'

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFileTransfer.m:56:30: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'CFIndex' (aka 'long')

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFileTransfer.m:67:12: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'CFIndex' (aka 'long')

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFileTransfer.m:281:46: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'unsigned long'

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVFileTransfer.m:282:100: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVURLProtocol.m:167:46: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'unsigned long'

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVURLProtocol.m:168:100: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:94:58: Undeclared selector 'presentViewController:::'

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:154:58: Undeclared selector 'presentViewController:::'

/Users/Webgrity/Desktop/BramAutoGroup/CordovaLib/Classes/CDVContacts.m:196:50: Undeclared selector 'presentViewController:::'
```

I have seen in every version since 2.2.0. Now I am using latest version too.

But it's really frustrating that every time when I am creating a new project XCode comes these 15  warnings. In fact in some of my old projects(already in apple store), these 15 warnings are there. As these were only the warnings, I used to avoid this.

But now it really becomes unbearable for me as there is no error and warning in my coding. So is there any problem of creating a new project by those steps or its a bug of phonegap? And if it is the problem of mine then can you please give me some idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: i also created iOS projects several time in Phone gap but didn't got such warning, it may be cause for using cordova version...

Comment: I have seen in every version since 2.2.0. Now I am using latest version too. @bhanu

Comment: stay away from these stuffs(HTML5,Titanium) for making a good app...!!

Comment: @user2416728 Thanks for kind reply. But just let me know onething if there is a any other way to make a cross-platform app.

Answer (score 0):

It's posible you have update to xcode 5.1 and your version cordova is very older. I advice you upgrade project in cordova to last version and xcode too.

Comment: My xcode and cordova version is very latest. And the worst thing is I have seen these warnings in previous version as well :(

Comment: I say you because the last version in corcova is 3.1 and me have same problem. Install last version cordova and xcode. Create new project clean for cordova and afther copy www (project with error) into new project and compile without problem

Comment: so are you telling me to install xcode 5.1 and cordova 3.4. right?

Comment: Yes, i have same versions now

Comment: But its throwing same warnings in this version too :(

Comment: Have create one new project and copy www files?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50660/discussion-between-avijit-and-roberto)